# Woocommerce single product gallery images cropped

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, hook-woocommerce

I'm using woocommerce hooks with thumbnail regenerate plugin but still have same issue i didn't see any changes in my website i removed cache as well.

add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_image_size_gallery_thumbnail', 'override_woocommerce_image_size_gallery_thumbnail');
function override_woocommerce_image_size_gallery_thumbnail( $size ) {
// Gallery thumbnails: proportional, max width 200px
return array(
'width'  => 100,
'height' => 100,
'crop'   => 0,
);
}

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to that is in the "Appearance / Customize" then Woocommerce. There you can choose how products images are cropped.